# Russian student visa

Tags: russia, study, nigerian-citizens

I am a Nigerian citizen and presently hold a Russian internship (Стажировка) Visa. I intend to obtain a Russian study visa from the nearest country to the Russian Federation. Can a Nigerian citizen obtain Russian study visa from Abkhazia?

Comment: Are you a resident in Abkhazia?

Comment: @Neusser one might suspect that the asker of the question is temporarily resident in Russia.

Answer (score 1):

If you're residing in Abkhazia, try to contact the [Russian Embassy in Sukhumi](http://www.abkhazia.mid.ru) so they can provide all the information you need, and the list of documents you'll need as well.

> phone: +7 840 2263693, 2260491
>   fax:     +7 840 2265693
>   E-mail: rusembsukhum@mail.ru
>           rusembsukhum@mid.ru
>   address: Sukhumi, Lakoba st, 45

However, getting into Abkhazia is quite tricky (as it's not an independent country, strictly speaking), and you need either russian visa or georgian to get into there, as no other countries has any travel connection with it.

Update: missed the part about your student visa, sorry. So, for obtaining visa to Abkhazia (which you need) you need to fill the electronic form for it and send it to embassy. Usually it takes up for 7 days to get the permission to enter the Abkhazia (take a note that this is a crime in Georgia for you to enter Abkhazia from Russian side). However, the Russian Embassy may have additional information - maybe you can apply for continuation of your visa without going to other country.

Comment: The question states that the prospective applicant has a Russian visa.